# Why session.createCriteria(classtype).list() return more object than in list?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Why session.createCriteria(classtype).list() return **more object than in list**?

Returned list is contains repeating objects in random order.

```
public Collection getAll() {
        List list = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            list = session.createCriteria(getClassType()).list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            LOGGER.error("HibernateException in getAll");
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: In this case how can i apply setMaxResults() to Criteria? Then i add setMaxResults(10000), i received only near 1200 different records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `session.createCriteria(classtype).list()` call is returning some of the objects of this class multiple times.

This can occur when you have a `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` relation that is eagerly fetched.

One way to solve this, as JB Nizet correctly points out, is to use the `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` `ResultTransformer`.

This, however, will do the work at the 'java side': all objects will be fetched from the database and then all duplicates are removed.

It would be much better to make the `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` lazy (which is the default) instead of eager.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the loaded entity has a toMany association that is eagerly fetched using a join. Use a distinct root entity result transformer to only get each root entity once in the list:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

or return a Set rather than a List if the order is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help, i used it, and resolve problem this way:

```
...
try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getClassType())
                .setProjection(Projections.id())
                .setFirstResult(getStart())
                .setMaxResults(getLength());    
            HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet( criteria.list() );            

            criteria = session.createCriteria(getClassType())
                .add(Restrictions.in(ID_COLUMN_NAME, ids))
            TreeSet<Employee> items = new TreeSet( criteria.list() );

            list = new ArrayList<Employee>(items);

            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
...
```